# How do I create a new copy of a signed PDF without signatures to make a template?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I cannot find anything on this that is helpful. Mostly it is about removing your own signatures to edit a PDF.

We have a PDF file that was signed, and the people who signed it have left the company. We need to create a new blank template based on this file, and no such template is available. I'd like to take the signed file we have and end up with an unsigned empty version of the same file.

I would think that *File → Save as Unsigned* would be an option, or delete signatures directly, etc. would work, but for no good reason, this isn't intuitive.

How can I get a blank unsigned copy of a signed PDF that was signed by someone else who is not available to remove their own signatures?

Comment: PDFs aren't generally the basis for a document. Meaning the actual document starts in some other app, then is exported/saved as a PDF. What about possibly finding the originating document and merely regenerating a PDF from that file?

Comment: Well, that would be ideal, but as I said, the originators are gone, and with them, their files are no longer accessible.

Comment: The point of signatures is that they should be tamper proof, no? Anyway you can open the document in inkscape that should remove all interactive stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that this is not possible. The only solution is to just retype the whole thing in Word and created a fresh PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard Adobe Reader to blank the signatures.  But, someone else can probably remove the blank.  Unless you print and scan.

1. Open the pdf in the standard Adobe reader
2. Click on `Fill & Sign` on the top right part of the menu
3. Select Place Signature
4. Select an appropriate piece of image in white
5. Place it where you want
6. Scale it to suit

Comment: This will not remove the signature, and the form will still be signed with its implications.

Comment: Theres no magic bullet, except OCR. if the pdf is printed and rescanned, then it will be clean.

Comment: And printing and rescanning is about the dumbest approach…

Comment: A dumb question needs a dumb approach.  If it's so important, the Op can pay someone to retype - it won't cost them an arm and a leg.  It is a pretty pathetic business if it cannot afford to do that.

Comment: If there were a "comment does not contribute to the question" mark, I would have checked it now.

There are no dumb questions!

Answer (score 0):

I have not verified it, but it should be possible, if the signatures were applied to signature fields to create a copy with the Save as a copy function. The resulting file should allow to remove signature fields.

As a last resort, you could "refry" the file, which means either sending it through a "create PDF" utility, or even create a PostScript file and create the PDF from it. Note that you lose a lot of information by that, and you will have to re-add fields etc. Therefore, it is a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to go to File > Save a Copy (NOT "Save As").  Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I am commenting here because I needed to find the answer and was able to do it easily by selecting "print" and choosing "adobe PDF" as the printer. Then just selecting the file destination and opening that document (it opened automatically for me after it was saved)
Hope this helps someone else.